# linq to entities where condition issue

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to list all the rows that satisfies either condition # 1 or #2 and returning both rows for #1 & #2. but the problem is returning only rows that satisfies one condition (#1 or #2).

```
    var query = (from c in context.Tasks where 
                && ((c.FK_PrivacyID == 1 && c.Fk_TaskFollowerTypeID == 1)  
                 || (c.TaskFollower == FK_userID && c.Fk_TaskFollowerTypeID == 2))
                  orderby c.CreatedDate descending
                  orderby c.LastModificationDate descending 
                  select c)).ToList();
```

Appreciate any help..

Comment: Fix your question. It says you want "either condition #1 or #2" but it is returning rows that satisfy "condition #1 or #2"

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you trying to get rows that satisfy `#1` or `#2`, but not both at the same time?

Comment: sorry..There are row the satisfy #1 but not #2 -->and I want to list them all. :\.. you can see that in case of c.Fk_TaskFollowerTypeID == 2 or 1

Answer (score 1):

You want condition 1 and not condition 2 -> (condition1) && !(condition2)

```
var query = (from c in context.Tasks where 
                ((c.FK_PrivacyID == 1 && c.Fk_TaskFollowerTypeID == 1)  
                 && !(c.TaskFollower == FK_userID && c.Fk_TaskFollowerTypeID == 2))
                  orderby c.CreatedDate descending
                  orderby c.LastModificationDate descending 
                  select c).ToList();
```

Comment: Not really.. sorry I couldn't explain it clearly. for example row [1,8] satisfy condition 1 and row [9,19] satisfy condition 2.. how can list rows from [1,19] since they satisfy the condition.

Comment: Then you really just want an or. Remove the initial && after where and a closing parenthesis before "ToList". jmd1921 's answer shows this

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the first "&&" after the where clause, and the unnecesary brackets

```
    var query = (from c in context.Tasks where 
            (c.FK_PrivacyID == 1 && c.Fk_TaskFollowerTypeID == 1)  
             || (c.TaskFollower == FK_userID && c.Fk_TaskFollowerTypeID == 2)
              orderby c.CreatedDate descending
              orderby c.LastModificationDate descending 
              select c)).ToList();
```

Comment: the first "&&"  is my mistake when copying the code.  I want the query to go for the two condition each one with it;s own data and OR would get me part of the result

Comment: I can no longer tell exactly what it is that you want. You need to be clearer.

Comment: So, what you actually want is to retrieve different data based on which of the conditions applies?